# Do "play immediately" cards in the zombie turn affect the number of cards a zombie player will have in his hand?

Tags: last-night-on-earth

This is probably a silly question, but I've just read the rulebook of "Last Night on Earth", and need a small clarification: the rulebook says that a zombie player must draw up to two cards at the start of his/her turn. It also says that the player must play immediately any "Play Immediately" cards that he/she draws from the zombie deck.

If I have no cards in hand, and one of the the cards I draw is a "Play Immediately" card - do I draw another card, so I'll have two cards in my hand, or does this count as though I've already drawn two cards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When playing as the zombie, you first fill your hand of cards (4 cards if there is 1 zombie player, 2 cards if there are 2 zombie players). After drawing all cards, you then decide in which order you would like to resolve all of the "play immediately" cards just drawn. After resolving these cards, they are not replaced.